# Define glDebugMessageCallbackARB callback method

Tags: c++, opengl

Im using glew to use openGL extensions. I am trying to use *GL_ARB_debug_output* extension.

I added the flag WGL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB while context creation, so context created with debug support.

While trying to define callback method for *glDebugMessageCallbackARB* i found the following function from a blog

```
void CALLBACK DebugCallback(unsigned int source, unsigned int type,
                            unsigned int id, unsigned int severity,
                            int length, const char* message, void* userParam);
```

but when add the line

```
glDebugMessageCallbackARB(&DebugCallback, NULL);
```

the following error is generated

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__stdcall *)(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,int,const char *,void *)' to 'GLDEBUGPROCARB'
```

Can any one help me to understand this error so that i can resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [official OpenGL header](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glext.h):

```
typedef void (APIENTRY *GLDEBUGPROCARB)(
    GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length,
    const GLchar *message, const void *userParam);
```

So the last argument needs to be `const void*` instead of the `void*` you tried. The rest of the arguments *might* be ok depending on how the GL types are defined on your platform. But it would be much safer to use the GL types in your function declaration.

Note that a core version of this was added in OpenGL 4.3. If you have 4.3 available, you can use `glDebugMessageCallback()` instead of `glDebugMessageCallbackARB()`. The corresponding callback declaration looks the same in the header:

```
typedef void (APIENTRY *GLDEBUGPROC)(
    GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length,
    const GLchar *message, const void *userParam);
```

There was no `const` for `userParam` in the 4.3 spec document, but the `const` was added in the 4.4 and 4.5 spec. From the change log in the 4.4 spec:

> Add const attribute to userParam argument of DebugMessageCallback and DEBUGPROC in section 20.2.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow found out that `GLDEBUGPROCARB` is prototyped as:

```
typedef GLvoid (APIENTRY *GLDEBUGPROCARB)(GLenum source, GLenum type, 
   GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, 
   const GLchar* message, GLvoid* userParam);
```

And therefore, your `DebugCallback` must of this prototype.